# Unable to save data in vfp dbf thourgh php

Tags: php, dbf, visual-foxpro

What im doing wrong, My code is in php and i want to save data into dbf.

I have tested this code in vfp and it is working

vfp code

```
hh='INSERT INTO instadb.db(pic_nm,user_pic,hashtag,usernm) values("abc","dd","eee","fff")'
hh1=CREATEOBJECT("ADODB.Connection")
hh1.Open("Provider=VFPOLEDB.1;Data Source=d:\newweb\inst\;Exclusive=NO;BackGroundFetch=NO;NULL=NO;Collate=MACHINE")
hh1.Execute(hh)
```

this code is working,

but in php

now im writing this code in php

```
<?php

$conn = new COM("ADODB.Connection") ;
$jj="Provider=VFPOLEDB.1;Data Source=d:\newweb\inst\;Exclusive=NO;BackGroundFetch=NO;NULL=NO;Collate=MACHINE";
$conn->Open("Provider=VFPOLEDB.1;Data Source=d:\newweb\inst\;Exclusive=NO;BackGroundFetch=NO;NULL=NO;Collate=MACHINE");
$dd="INSERT INTO instadb.db(pic_nm,user_pic,hashtag,usernm) values('abc','dd','eee','fff')";
$conn->Execute($dd);
$conn->Close();

?>
```

This is not working, Please let me know what is the issue

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the connection string in single quotes:

```
$jj='Provider=VFPOLEDB.1;Data Source=d:\newweb\inst\;Exclusive=NO;BackGroundFetch=NO;NULL=NO;Collate=MACHINE';
```

While it is wrapped in double quotes

```
d:\newweb\inst\
```

becomes

```
d:
ewweb\inst\
```

...because PHP converts the `\n` to a new line.

Comment: I have changed this d:\newweb\inst\ to d:\NEWWEB\inst\, and it is working now, Thanks

Comment: Yes, I suppose that would work too. I personally prefer to keep the casing of all my path names the same as they are in the file system for *nix portability, but I suppose with Windows-specific code like this it really doesn't matter. Note that simply changing you quote style from double quotes to single quotes would do the job, but whatever works for you :-)